Русский язык в консоли С17
Не получается поставить русский язык в консоли. Начал изучать С, и не могу найти как мне сделать так, чтобы отображался русский язык в консоли. Пробовал в VS Code, почему то не отображается. Писал setlocale, кодировка меняется, но русской не становиться.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(void)
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    printf(" используем версию языка %d\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
    return 0;
}



Судя по выводу, у вас исходник в кодировке utf-8, попробуйте пересохранить в cp1251
